# Informatica Testing: Date Ranges

Tags: testing, informatica

this forum may not be the correct place for such a question, but I can't find a decent software testing forum out there.  With that said, I am wondering how to comprehensively test the following code.

```
if(date_1 <= MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 >= MIN_PROC_DATE){
    // do some stuff
}
```

What should my test cases be?  I figure with three possibilities for each comparison, there should be 9 total unique cases.

1. date_1 < MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 > MIN_PROC_DATE
2. date_1 = MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 > MIN_PROC_DATE
3. date_1 < MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 = MIN_PROC_DATE
4. date_1 = MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 = MIN_PROC_DATE
5. date_1 > MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 > MIN_PROC_DATE
6. date_1 < MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 < MIN_PROC_DATE
7. date_1 > MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 < MIN_PROC_DATE
8. date_1 = MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 < MIN_PROC_DATE
9. date_1 > MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 = MIN_PROC_DATE

Could some of these be combined?  Like does Test case 4 cover test cases 2 and 3 for testing that the program recognizes when the dates are equal? Please let me know your thoughts.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The && operator is a short-circuit, and therefore anything on the left that is `false` in turn makes everything on the right `false`.

Therefore the result is:

```
1  => always false => date 2 > IN_PROC_DATE
2  => always false => date_2 > MIN_PROC_DATE
5  => always false => date_1 > MAX_PROC_DATE
7  => always false =>  date_1 > MAX_PROC_DATE
9  => always false => date_1 > MAX_PROC_DATE

3 date_1 < MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 = MIN_PROC_DATE
4 date_1 = MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 = MIN_PROC_DATE
6 date_1 < MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 < MIN_PROC_DATE
8 date_1 = MAX_PROC_DATE && date_2 < MIN_PROC_DATE
```

So 3, 4, 6 and 8 will trigger your `//if done` part, but the others won't.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I am doing this in Informatica...  I don't know if it uses short-circuit logic or not.